# Find all integer solutions to $p^n+n=(n+1)^k$ where p is a prime of the form $2^m+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations, fermat-numbers

> Find all integer solutions to :
>   $$p^n+n=(n+1)^k,$$
>
> where $p$ is a prime of the form $2^m+1$.

I tried using binomial expansion and substituting $n$ with $c\times 2^m$ where c is a real number... but this seems to get nowhere.

Comment: Have you found any examples?  There are so few (known) primes of the form $2^m+1$...just pick one and search.

Comment: Note:  since no one knows if there are Fermat primes greater than $65,537$ a full solution for your problem will require you to eliminate all large $p$.

Comment: @lulu Is $p$ a prime? I don’t think the redaction states that explicitly.

Comment: Even if I use fermat prime it doesn't really help

Comment: And sorry i should've said where c is a real number

Comment: @URL  In the title it states that $p$ is a prime.

Comment: Once again;  search for examples.  There are two cheap examples (small numbers)...not sure there are any other.

Comment: $3^{1}+1=(3+1)^{1} \ \ $  and  $\ \ 5^{2}+2=(2+1)^{3}$ are solutions.

Comment: @Martin Hopf Are those the only possible solutions?

Comment: we can't find all the Fermat primes so we have to take other approaches, things like Polynomial remainder theorem, Fermat's little theorem, Freshman's dream, etc.

Comment: This is a Problem 4 from Olympic Revenge 2013 and seems to be solved here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h518185. Found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24p%5En%2Bn%3D(n%2B1)%5Ek%24&p=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not a full answer (Observations/Research):**

- By Polynomial Remainder Theorem, we have that the RHS has remainder 1 on division by $n$
- By observation, the LHS has the same remainder as $p^n$ Which by previous statement, and equality, means it has remainder 1.
- By a consequence of Lagrange's theorem in group theory, we have that the order of $p \pmod n$ divides the order of the group $Z/nZ$.
- By Euler's totient theorem, we have the order of the group, divides $\varphi (n)$, implying via previous observations that $n\over \varphi (n)$ is integer.
- Assuming $n$ is prime for a moment, we get the LHS is $p\pmod n$, therefore implying  $p\equiv 1\pmod n$ by previous observations. This further would imply that, $n$ divides $p-1$ which is a power of 2
- etc.

Comment: I don't see how n can divide p-1... can you elaborate your proof behind that conclusion?